# Настройка ЧПУ на .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache, чпу

есть ссылка site.com/car.php?id=111

хотелось бы дать ему вид типа site.com/car/111

конструкция такого вида выдает ошибку 500

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^car/([0-9]+)/? car.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Подскажите как. Спасибо!

Comment: У вас установлен mod_rewrite? Включен? Первое дело при получении ошибок - смотреть в лог (error.log)

Comment: Вероятно также, что в document_root отсутствует car.php - в любом случае всё написано в логе